# Code to spoof MAC address on startup?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-11, mac-address

Is there a way to randomize MAC address every time on startup.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WiFi or ethernet?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

For WiFi this can be done in
*Settings > Network & Internet > WiFi*,
by enabling "Use random hardware addresses".

For any other type of network interface, you may use the free
[Random MAC Address](https://www.trishtech.com/2019/03/set-random-mac-address-to-any-network-interface-in-windows/):

[image]

I counsel creating at least a System Restore point before using
this program.

If this change gets you in trouble, see the article
[6 ways to restore the original MAC address of your network card](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-restore-your-network-cards-original-mac-address/).

(Note that future Windows versions may disable the feature used
by this program.)